# Vertx JDBC Client Rows Updated Count

Tags: jdbc, vert.x

Using the Vertx SQL Client API (https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-jdbc-client/java/#_using_the_sql_client_api) how can I execute an update and get the number or rows updated to tell me if the update was a success.

I used LAST_INSERTED_ID for inserts, but what about updates and deletes?

```
return db.client.preparedQuery(
          "DELETE FROM table WHERE id = ?")
        .execute(Tuple.of(id))
        .map(rs -> rs.property(MySQLClient.?????)
        );
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not a query, it's an update, and the row count should be returned directly by the API, not as a property.

Comment: The Vertx SQL Client does not have a prepareUpdate or any of the normal execute methods...

Answer (score 2):

The number of affected rows should be given by the [`SqlResult.rowCount()`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/sqlclient/SqlResult.html#rowCount--) method:

```
db.client.preparedQuery("DELETE FROM table WHERE id = ?")
    .execute(Tuple.of(id))
    .map(res -> {
        int count = res.rowCount());
        return count;
    })
);
```